lambda cannot find S3 bucket
I have a lambda in which I am making an api call to get some stock data and then want to write the csv to a bucket. When I run from home in python 3.9.7, it works fine. Lambda is python 3.11. When I try using python 3.9.7, I still have the same error, so, the problem is apparently not related to that.
Here is the error I get in the lambda:
An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation

I am running the lambda with IAM role which has nested "AmazonS3FullAccess" policy
My bucket has "Block Public access" set to "On" and there is no bucket policy.
Object ownership is set to Bucket Owner. Access control list is default. Bucket and lambda are in the same region. I also have a layer in the lambda (AWSSDKPandas-Python311)
here is my code:
import awswrangler as wr
import time
from datetime import date, timedelta
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    today = date.today()
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
    
    exchanges = ["SR"]
    
    SMTP_SERVER = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
    SMTP_PORT = 587  # Update to the appropriate port
    SMTP_USERNAME = '99999999999'
    SMTP_PASSWORD = '999d9999999999999999'
    
    # Sender and recipient email addresses
    SENDER_EMAIL = '9999@olaptrader.com'
    RECIPIENT_EMAILS = ['973999999@vtext.com', '9999@olaptrader.com']
    
    
    
    def send_email(subject, body):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = SENDER_EMAIL
        msg['To'] = ', '.join(RECIPIENT_EMAILS)
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    
        try:
            with smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT) as server:
                server.starttls()
                server.login(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD)
                server.sendmail(SENDER_EMAIL, RECIPIENT_EMAILS, msg.as_string())
                print(f"Email sent successfully: {subject}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Email sending failed: {str(e)}")
    
    
    try:
        for ex in exchanges:
    
            df = wr.s3.read_json(
                f's3://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod-bulk-last-day/{ex}?api_token=5f199920.009991&fmt=json&date={str(today)}',
                dtype={'code': str})
    
            print(df.head(5))
            if not df.empty:
    
                df = df.dropna(thresh=7)
                print(df.tail(5))
                x = df['code'].astype(str)
    
                Ticker = x.str.slice(0, 38)
    
                Exchange = df['exchange_short_name']
                Date = df['date']
                Open = df['open']
                High = df['high']
                Low = df['low']
                Close = df['close']
                Volume = df['volume']
    
    
                total_df = wr.pandas.concat([Ticker, Exchange, Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume],
                                     axis=1, keys=['Ticker', 'Exchange', 'Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])
    
                filename = f"{ex}_{str(now)}.csv"
                path = 's3://olaptrader-9999/'
                full_path = path + filename
                
                wr.s3.to_csv(total_df, full_path, index=False)
    
    
    except Exception as e:
    
        error_message = f"Error occurred in '{ex}' ingestion: {str(e)}"
        print(error_message)
        print(e)
    
        #send_email(f"{error_message}: Error in '{ex}' ingestion", str(e))

what am I missing here?
update, I have also tried by using boto library and this variation but got the same error
bucket_name = 'olaptrader-9999'
filename = f"{ex}_{str(now)}.csv"
key = f"{filename}"
csv_buffer = total_df.to_csv(index=False)
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key, Body=csv_buffer)

(An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation)

I now gotten past this error by using pandas instead of awswrangler. I did not think my lambda layer had pandas in it. I am now getting a blank dataframe. I can curl to the endpoint in cloudshell and get data, but not from the lambda. I think I may have to modify permissions for the IAM role that the lambda uses. Either that, or I need a NAT gateway.
Final resolution. I did not need nat gateway or different IAM policy. I was getting an empty payload because the lambda was in UTC and therefore, was past midnight. There will be empty payload after midnight, until 5 am the next day. So, the main issue was resolved by using pandas instead of awswranger. Thanks for all suggestions.

Which line is generating the error? Is it total_df.to_csv()?

To use S3 URIs, I believe that you need the underlying s3fs file system interface to be running. It's not running in the OS underpinning AWS Lambda. You should use native boto3 functions instead, for example write your CSV to Lambda's local /tmp folder and then copy from there to S3 using boto3's put_object.

John, that line was supposed to be commented. I believe the line that generates the error is: wr.s3.to_csv(total_df, full_path, index=False)

Thanks Jarmond, I will think about this.

eodhistoricaldata.com requires a custom endpoint, which you may have configured on your local machine, but how have you configured it on Lambda?

When you are creating the boto s3 client try to set the region explicitly also check the bucket if the lambda and bukets if they are in same or different regions

So, the main issue was resolved by using pandas instead of awswrangler. After I started to get it to work, but with empty payload, I thought I needed an IAM role change or NAT gateway, but I did not. I was getting an empty payload because the lambda was in UTC and therefore, was past midnight. There will be empty payload after midnight, until 5 am the next day. Thanks for all suggestions.
